# Variable of known type becomes "undefined" when passed from server side (.gs) to client-side(html) in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

In google apps script, i've got an html file with an onsuccess callback function that calls a server side function, which grabs some data from the spreadsheet in question, then should return the data, stored in a variable, back to the html script function onsuccess.

i've already done this before successfully. this is why i am so perplexed at why, for some reason, the variable that i am returning from server side becomes 'undefined' once it is back to client side function.

i assumed it is some kind of Type Error, so i've played around with converting the variable (which is a very small array with three elements at most) and/or elements of the array to known types (string, int) and then pushing those into new variables and making a new array that contains the new known-type elements. also checked the original array elements using "typeof", and they are strings, as expected, so i became even more confused, because it doesn't seem like a TypeError.

html call-back function: (edited down to show essentials)

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(

          function (flavors) 
           {            
            console.log(flavors);  // undefined
           }
        ).getBatchFlavs();
```

---

code.gs: (edited down to show essentials)

```
function getBatchFlavs() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Flavoring");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var flavCell = sheet.getRange(1,3);

  data.forEach(function(row,i) {

    var rule = flavCell.getDataValidation();

      if (rule != null) 
        {
          var flavs = rule.getCriteriaValues(); 
          var flavors = flavs[0]; 

          Logger.log(flavors);  // shows exactly what i'm expecting
          Logger.log(typeof flavors);                 

          return flavors;  
        }
  })
}
```

console.log prints "undefined".

I included the part of the .gs code where i am getting the data for the variable i want to pass to client-side from a cell with datavalidation options which are strings. i thought perhaps this may be creating some weird variable type or something unknown, but as i said, i already checked the type with "typeof" and the items in the flavors array are indeed strings.

Comment: Are you using any libraries?

Comment: no just plain old apps script default stuff. regular .html and regular .gs files as GAS creates them when creating a new script file. as i mentioned in original post, i have already passed variables this way before between server and client with no issue. the variable arrives back at the callback function usually as an array of strings or integers and all works perfectly. i have cross-checked this code in question with those other instances where it is working, and they are identical. so i'm wondering if the issue is some kind of glitch on google's side?

Comment: possibly, but  you should exclude all other issues first. Can you try `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(

          function (flavors) 
           {            
            console.log(flavors);  // undefined
           }
        ).getBatchFlavs();` `function getBatchFlavs(){return 'vanilla'};`? Also make sure you deployed the app again at a `New` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- There's no return value from the server side function `getBatchFlavs()`. The `return flavors;` only returns the value to anonymous callback function passed to the `Array#forEach`.

#### Solution:

- `return` something from the function called from `google.script.run`-`getBatchFlavs()`

#### Snippet:

```
function getBatchFlavs() {//<================
  data.forEach(function(row, i) {//<==      |
    if (rule != null) {//            |      |
      var flavors = flavs[0];//      |      |
      Logger.log(flavors); //        |      |
      return flavors;//==============       |
    }//                                     |
  });//                                     |
  return flavors;//=========================
}
```

Comment: thank you! perfect solution. one thing i had tried was moving the "return flavors;" statement out of one of the if statements, but hadn't tried getting it all the way out of the forEach loop. makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions in what can be passed. Please read this [Parameters & Return Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

I did this example and this works:

```
function showmydialog() {
  var html='<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></head><body>';
  html+='<div id="tst"></div>';
  html+='<script>$(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(vA){$("#tst").html(vA.join());}).getMyFlavors();});</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Flavors");
}

function getMyFlavors() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A1');//this has the data validation from the flavors named range
  var rule = rg.getDataValidation();
  if (rule != null) 
  {
    var flavs = rule.getCriteriaValues();      
    //return flavs[0].getValues();  
    return rule.getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}); //This should flatten out the array.
  }
}
```

I created a named range called flavors.

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

This is what my dialog looks like:

[image]

The data gets loaded onto the page via the dom ready function.

Comment: indeed there are, but as you can see i am not passing anything unusual. it is an array consisting of a few strings.

Comment: i just tried returning "hello world" from the .gs file and i still get undefined on client side. is this a glitch? any ideas are much appreciated! thanks cooper for your first reply

Comment: I did an example of my own and I got it to work above.

Comment: thank you cooper, your example solution also points out my error in needing to re-locate the return statement so that the getBatchFlavs() function is returning the variable to client, rather than feeding it back to forEach loop. thx again